# have you seen false calims of code using ChatGPT in Arbitrage strategy and slippage?

Tags: solidity, transactions, arbitrage, trust, code

I have seen identical videos on you tube and in other sites claiming to make passive income through code from ChatGPT in Arbitrage strategy and slippage.

ALL FAKE and will take your ETHER.  If this has a chance of being true, the code would be same on all videos.  I noticed code was identical except for this three items, all different on every video. This was a clue that this is being replicated to steal your ether and send to different wallets as videos or codes get found and exposed.

bytes32 apiKey = .....;
bytes32 DexRouter = .....;
bytes32 factory = .....;

My assumption is that these fields in the code are linked to the thief's wallet and if you execute and follow guides, you will loose your ether.

Let me know if I am correct here please.

Comment: You are correct. YT videos that are a week old or less, with a lot of generic comments saying they have won hundreds of dollars in one day, almost no negative comments. The videos are short, they only explain how to deploy the contract. There is no explanation how it works. The links are to new sites, or pastebin like sites. They don't use well known pages like remix but some shady clones that are slow.